# How to rotate google map markers to road direction

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

[ Flutter / Dart ]
**I need to create a map where dozens of cars will move and for each of them I need to rotate the icon in the direction of travel. Any ideas how to do this?**

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EQtj.png)

Comment: You can use the `flutter_animarker` package that will allow you to rotate the marker that can be useful for Uber-like or delivery apps.  You can check it here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker

Comment: @jabamataro , unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
Marker(
    markerId: const MarkerId("MarkerIdHere"),
    rotation: location.heading,
    //anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
    position: LatLng(
        location.latitude, location.longitude),
  );
```